# Why is it impossible to construct private objects through reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection, parameterized-types

I clearly set the constructor's setAccessible to true, but why is it still an error! can you tell me how to fix it

```
public class Person {
    // fields...

    private Person(String name, int age, String address, int num) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.num = num;
        System.out.println("private full-constructor be created");
    }

}
```

// error happend ?! why?

```
public static void operatePrivateConstructorFullParameter(Class<? extends Person> clzz) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    Constructor<? extends Person> constructor = clzz.getConstructor(String.class, int.class, String.class, int.class);
    constructor.setAccessible(true);

    Person person = constructor.newInstance("Miao", 18, "MOON", 88);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<? extends Person> clzz = Person.class;
    operatePrivateConstructorFullParameter(clzz);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add error messages as text not as image

Answer (score 6):

This error isn't about accessibility, it's about finding the constructor.

As specified in its documented contract, the method [`Class.getConstructor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) will only find *public* constructors.

If you want to find this private constructor, you need to use [`getDeclaredConstructor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) with the correct parameter types

Once you find the constructor, you will still need to make it accessible. Be aware, however, that in a modular application, encapsulation can prevent you from using reflection this way.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer, because my carelessness got you into trouble. When I saw getDeclaredConstructor(), I had a sudden realization, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Constructor<Person> constructor= (Constructor<Person>) Person.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
```